# Max determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Working on a 5x5 matrix the max determinant I figured out so far is 4.The entries I'm using is 0 and 1 . Is that the only determinant or is there bigger determinant than 4?

Answer (score 3):

This is the [Hadamard maximum determinant problem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HadamardsMaximumDeterminantProblem.html) when $n=5$. The maximum possible determinant should be $5$, which is realised by, for instance, the following matrix:
$$
\pmatrix{
1&1&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&1&1\\
0&0&1&1&0\\
1&0&1&0&1\\
0&1&1&0&1}.
$$